# How is "gomen" used?

Tags: words

I don't even know if this is the correct place to post this. The only source that I'm in touch with the Japanese language is through anime. So my question, which I understand that could be kinda silly,

Gomen'nasai translates to I'm sorry.
Kiri-sute gomen is the right for a Samurai to "Cut and leave" in case a commoner insults his honor

So does "gomen" mean something literally ? or is it an untranslatable word?

Comment: ごめん(御免) has other uses too, like ごめんだ and ごめんください.

Comment: @snailboat ごめんください is a dialect, in particular the phrase is typical for Niigata prefecture, but not used normally. Same with ごめんだ。

Comment: @Rilakkuma: It may be common in Niigata (I don't know) but one of my early textbooks taught that ごめんください  meant excuse me, it could be used when coming into a someone's house or a room and it could also be used as goodbye.

Comment: @Rilakkuma What makes you think so?

Comment: @snailboat well, first of all I never heard anyone to say "ごめんください" considering 100% of people around speak Japanese. But this is Tokyo. So I googled around and found out several references to ごめんください as Niigata dialect.

Comment: I've heard it in dramas based in Tokyo....

Comment: @Rilakkuma I've heard people in the Nagoya area say ごめんください when walking into a neighbor's yard without their perimssion. Like saying お邪魔します when entering a house.

Comment: I've also seen ごめんください used in a couple anime in a similar fashion (i.e. as a sort of "Hello, anyone home?"), and I think they were based in Tokyo.

Comment: This discussion is so funny.  Tokyoites say ごめんください all the time when entering another person's home.  I cannot even think of another phrase that could replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word ごめん (gomen) essentially means "forgive" or "pardon". ごめんなさい (gomen nasai) is a common phrase that literally means "forgive me" or "pardon me", and ごめん (gomen) or ごめんね (gomen ne) is a more colloquial way to say the same thing. Like saying "sorry" instead of saying "I am sorry".

I don't know much about samurai-era Japanese, and so I've never heard "kiri-sute gomen" before. But assuming it's written 切り捨てごめん, <strike>then it would presumably mean something like "forgive them by cutting them and throwing them away"</strike>.

**Correction:**
Based on [the defintion Darius Jahandarie linked in the comments](http://www.fleapedia.com/%E4%BA%94%E5%8D%81%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9/%E3%81%8D/%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A%E6%8D%A8%E3%81%A6%E5%BE%A1%E5%85%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B/), The meaning of "Kirisute gomen" is more like "pardoned for cutting and throwing away" and refers to the special right of being able to kill someone of a low station and not be charged with a crime. Essentially, a "license to kill" (legal pardon for killing). According to the same article, it was not a general license to kill in every situation, but was to be exercised in accord with the warrior customs of the time.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie - Fair enough. As I admitted, I was only speculating. I'll add your reference to my answer.

Comment: This is a quote from dictionary, could be interesting regarding "licences":
ごめん：
① 免許許可の尊敬語。「お出入り―になる」「天下―」「木戸―」
② 免官免職の尊敬語。「お役を―になる」

Comment: hey guys great answer thank you very much!